# Request for yet another one liner in Python

Tags: python, append

Can you guys think of any one liners equal to if/else statements:

```
d = dict()

key = 1, 2

if key in d:
    d[key]['idx'] += [2]
else:
    d[key] = {'idx': [2]}

print d
```

?

EDIT:
Thanks guys. You narrowed me to collection.defaultdict & dict.setdafault and with this in mind I was able to achieve what I wanted:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = dict()
key = 1, 2
d.setdefault(key, {'idx': []})
d[key]['idx'] += [2]
```

Maybe it is not one liner as it spreads over 2 lines (setdefault() call and then in place addition), but looks nicer though.

But still, if anyone have any ideas how to make it real one liner please share it.

Comment: Why the apparent obsession with one-liners?

Comment: @NPE that seems to be a constant among Python programmers. Just saying.

Comment: Its getting a bit of a pain in the ass. JUST DO IT IN MORE THAN ONE LINE

Comment: I'm total python beginner, but as far as I know 'one-liners' seem to be faster than code split in multiple lines. Considering given code will be called frequently in a loop (thousand of times) I was hoping for some premature optimization

Comment: @user1804668 Ask if there is a way to make the code more efficient then. Why ask for something other than your actual goal?

Comment: one-liners ARE NOT per se faster! what you probably mean is that some loop-constructions (mainly for-loops) are slower then functional-programming solutions or list-comprehension which fit in a line...    But you should remind yourself of two fundamental truths: the biggest optimazation is the jump from a not working idea to a working implementation and if it's not broken don't try to fix it! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to do things in multiple lines, this is one of those cases.  However sometimes it is reasonable to try to avoid this sort of "does this key exist" logic, and to do that you can use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [`dict.setdefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).  And now just for fun, here is a horrible one-liner that you should not use (but is equivalent in behavior to your if/else):

```
d.setdefault(key, {'idx': []})['idx'] += [2] if d[key]['idx'] else [1]
```

Note that this is less efficient than your original version, because it requires additional lookups, and creates unnecessary objects each time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
d = dict()
key = 1,2

d[key] = (d[key]['idx'] + [2] if key in d and 'idx' in d[key] else {'idx': [2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
key=1,2
d={key:'idx'}
d[key]['idx'] = d[key]['idx']+[2] if key in d else ['2']
```